# Хочу добавить на сайт карту гугл

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

Как добавить на сайт карту гугл, чтобы показывало точный адрес местонахождения офиса, например 
Где есть инфа ?

Comment: вам надо вставить карту в виде IFRAME или же  по API ?

Comment: @Arsen я думал там есть какая-то API, хотелось бы о ней узнать

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ru

Comment: можно конечно так, но это для чего то большего. Если у вас лендинг и нужна карта с 1 меткой, то лучше вставить https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide?hl=ru